# python doesn't access an async function

Tags: python, function, kivy

I am new to the kivy framework and I wish to control TP-Link smart plugs using the python-kasa library.

```
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.list import MDList, OneLineListItem

from kivy.metrics import dp
from kasa import Discover
from kasa import SmartPlug
from kasa import SmartDevice
import asyncio

async def SeekDevices(MDList):
        found_devices = asyncio.run(Discover.discover())
        for dev in found_devices.items():
            item = OneLineListItem(text=dev.alias)
            MDList.add_widget(item)

class DemoApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        screen = Screen()
        list = MDList()
        SeekDevices(list)
        screen.add_widget(list)
        return screen
            

DemoApp().run()
```

This code is supposed to create a list of discovered devices within my wifi network. However, the compiler does not seem to go through the SeekDevices function I created.

Did I do something wrong here?

Comment: Don't you get an error?  You can't just call an async function from a sync function.  You need `asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(SeekDevices(list))`.

Comment: I did not get an error, It just simply just ignores the function and compiles.